Cuda compile error "LNK2001: unresolved external symbol threadIdx"
i create cuda project in qt creator.this is cmake code
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
#set(CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER "nvcc")
project(OpenGLCuda VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CUDA CXX)
# set(CUDA_64_BIT_DEVICE_CODE_DEFAULT ON)


set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)




find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.cpp
        mainwindow.cpp
        mainwindow.h
        mainwindow.ui
        #kernel.cu
)

if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(OpenGLCuda
        MANUAL_FINALIZATION
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        #kernel.cu
    )
# Define target properties for Android with Qt 6 as:
#    set_property(TARGET OpenGLCuda APPEND PROPERTY QT_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR
#                 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android)
# For more information, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt-add-executable.html#target-creation
else()
    if(ANDROID)
        add_library(OpenGLCuda SHARED
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
# Define properties for Android with Qt 5 after find_package() calls as:
#    set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android")
    else()
        add_executable(OpenGLCuda
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
            kernel.cu
        )
    endif()
endif()

target_link_libraries(OpenGLCuda PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets)


# if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD)
#     message(STATUS "NOT DEFINED CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD")
#     set(CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD 11)
#     set(CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
# endif()
# set_target_properties(OpenGLCuda PROPERTIES
#                             CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)

find_package(CUDAToolkit REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "Found CUDA ${CUDA_VERSION_STRING} at ${CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR}")
target_link_libraries(OpenGLCuda PRIVATE CUDA::cudart CUDA::cudart_static)


# set(CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER "C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v12.5\\bin\\nvcc.exe")

#set(CUDA_LINK_LIBRARIES_KEYWORD PUBLIC)


# if(_cuda_build_shared_libs)
#   # If we are setting up code for a shared library, then we need to add extra flags for
#   # compiling objects for shared libraries.
#   set(CUDA_HOST_SHARED_FLAGS ${CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_${CUDA_C_OR_CXX}_FLAGS})
# else()
#   set(CUDA_HOST_SHARED_FLAGS)
# endif()

# Locate sources and headers for this project
# find_package(CUDA QUIET)
# include_directories(${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS})
# SET(ALL_CUDA_LIBS ${CUDA_LIBRARIES} ${CUDA_cusparse_LIBRARY} ${CUDA_cublas_LIBRARY})
# SET(LIBS ${LIBS} ${ALL_CUDA_LIBS})



# Compile Info
set_target_properties(OpenGLCuda PROPERTIES CUDA_ARCHITECTURES all)
target_compile_features(OpenGLCuda PUBLIC cxx_std_11)
target_compile_features(OpenGLCuda PUBLIC cuda_std_11)
set_target_properties(OpenGLCuda PROPERTIES CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)
set_source_files_properties(kernel.cu PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CUDA)


# Qt for iOS sets MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER automatically since Qt 6.1.
# If you are developing for iOS or macOS you should consider setting an
# explicit, fixed bundle identifier manually though.
if(${QT_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 6.1.0)
  set(BUNDLE_ID_OPTION MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER com.example.OpenGLCuda)
endif()
set_target_properties(OpenGLCuda PROPERTIES
    ${BUNDLE_ID_OPTION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS OpenGLCuda
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)

if(QT_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 6)
    qt_finalize_executable(OpenGLCuda)
endif()



when i tried to compile the code,i receive this error
"error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol threadIdx"
i am using msvc 2022 pe-x64 kit in QT-Creator.Cuda Version is 12.5 and sample codes are successfully compile in visual studio
i  tried commented codes in cmake but none of these working
this is kernel.cu code.(i removed other parts untile error gone):
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>
int f1()
{
    printf("C++ version: %ld\n", __cplusplus);
    return  0;
}

cudaError_t addWithCuda(int *c, const int *a, const int *b, unsigned int size);

__global__ void addKernel(int *c, const int *a, const int *b)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}


Can you please share your kernel.cu and/or wherever your main is?

i add kernel.cu code

It seems you are not using any Qt library but your CMake is has a lot of Qt and OpenGL links and is rather quite involved. Care to explain? I suggest to incrementally add packages and stuff and to find the mistake when you run in a compile error.

Also, I am not exactly 100% sure, but try using <cuda_runtime.h> rather than in quotes in your main.cu. Because in quotes, it means you are calling from your local directory (where your kernel.cu is) and not from where nvcc has its headers.

im using Qt Forms( mainwindow.cpp,mainwindow.h, mainwindow.ui).this is my sample project and in main.cpp i call function from kernel.cu.

Have you tried changing to <cuda_runtime.h> ?

there is no difference

I am on CUDA 12.2 and used CMake 3.30. There were a few fundamental problems in your code which I fixed. I am using the following CMake which is exactly yours but with main.cu instead of kernel.cu.
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
#set(CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER "nvcc")
project(OpenGLCuda VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CUDA CXX)
# set(CUDA_64_BIT_DEVICE_CODE_DEFAULT ON)


set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)




find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.cu
)

if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(OpenGLCuda
        MANUAL_FINALIZATION
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        #kernel.cu
    )
# Define target properties for Android with Qt 6 as:
#    set_property(TARGET OpenGLCuda APPEND PROPERTY QT_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR
#                 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android)
# For more information, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt-add-executable.html#target-creation
else()
    if(ANDROID)
        add_library(OpenGLCuda SHARED
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
# Define properties for Android with Qt 5 after find_package() calls as:
#    set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android")
    else()
        add_executable(OpenGLCuda
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
                main.cu
        )
    endif()
endif()

target_link_libraries(OpenGLCuda PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets)


# if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD)
#     message(STATUS "NOT DEFINED CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD")
#     set(CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD 11)
#     set(CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
# endif()
# set_target_properties(OpenGLCuda PROPERTIES
#                             CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)

find_package(CUDAToolkit REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "Found CUDA ${CUDA_VERSION_STRING} at ${CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR}")
target_link_libraries(OpenGLCuda PRIVATE CUDA::cudart CUDA::cudart_static)


# set(CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER "C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v12.5\\bin\\nvcc.exe")

#set(CUDA_LINK_LIBRARIES_KEYWORD PUBLIC)


# if(_cuda_build_shared_libs)
#   # If we are setting up code for a shared library, then we need to add extra flags for
#   # compiling objects for shared libraries.
#   set(CUDA_HOST_SHARED_FLAGS ${CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_${CUDA_C_OR_CXX}_FLAGS})
# else()
#   set(CUDA_HOST_SHARED_FLAGS)
# endif()

# Locate sources and headers for this project
# find_package(CUDA QUIET)
# include_directories(${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS})
# SET(ALL_CUDA_LIBS ${CUDA_LIBRARIES} ${CUDA_cusparse_LIBRARY} ${CUDA_cublas_LIBRARY})
# SET(LIBS ${LIBS} ${ALL_CUDA_LIBS})



# Compile Info
set_target_properties(OpenGLCuda PROPERTIES CUDA_ARCHITECTURES all)
target_compile_features(OpenGLCuda PUBLIC cxx_std_11)
target_compile_features(OpenGLCuda PUBLIC cuda_std_11)
set_target_properties(OpenGLCuda PROPERTIES CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)
set_source_files_properties(main.cu PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CUDA)


# Qt for iOS sets MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER automatically since Qt 6.1.
# If you are developing for iOS or macOS you should consider setting an
# explicit, fixed bundle identifier manually though.
if(${QT_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 6.1.0)
  set(BUNDLE_ID_OPTION MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER com.example.OpenGLCuda)
endif()
set_target_properties(OpenGLCuda PROPERTIES
    ${BUNDLE_ID_OPTION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS OpenGLCuda
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)

if(QT_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 6)
    qt_finalize_executable(OpenGLCuda)
endif()

Then here is the main.cu
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define SIZE 1024

__global__ void addKernel(const float *a, const float *b, float *c, int size)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    if (i < size) {
        c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
}

int main()
{
    float *a , *b , *c;
    float *d_a , *d_b , *d_c;

    a = (float *)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(float));
    b = (float *)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(float));
    c = (float *)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(float));

    cudaMalloc( &d_a , SIZE * sizeof(float) );
    cudaMalloc( &d_b , SIZE * sizeof(float) );
    cudaMalloc( &d_c , SIZE * sizeof(float) );

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < SIZE ; ++i)
    {
        a[i] = sin(i)*sin(i) ;
        b[i] = cos(i)*cos(i) ;
        c[i] = 0 ;
    }

    cudaMemcpy(d_a, a, SIZE *sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_b, b, SIZE *sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_c, c, SIZE *sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    addKernel<<< 1, SIZE >>>(d_a, d_b, d_c, SIZE);

    cudaMemcpy(c, d_c, SIZE * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i)
    {
        printf("C[%d] =  %f\n", i, c[i]);
    }

    free(a);
    free(b);
    free(c);

    cudaFree(d_a);
    cudaFree(d_b);
    cudaFree(d_c);

    return 0;
}

It’s a simple example of sin(x)^2 + cos(x)^2 = 1 (i.e. the c array should be 1’s).
As it is , here is my output.
C[0] =  1.000000
C[1] =  1.000000
C[2] =  1.000000
C[3] =  1.000000
C[4] =  1.000000
C[5] =  1.000000
C[6] =  1.000000
C[7] =  1.000000
C[8] =  1.000000
C[9] =  1.000000

I had a build folder where the CMakeLists.txt and main.cu is, and ran cmake .. && make and ran the OpenGLCuda executable like this ./OpenGLCuda.
Bear in mind I’m on a Linux system, and cannot help much with Microsoft Windows based platforms / Visual Studio configuration.
